# Ocultar un registro de la base de datos mysql

Tags: java, sql

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en java que conecta con una base de datos mysql.
Tengo un jtable que recoge los datos de una tabla de la base de datos.
Necesito que cuando seleccione un registro en el jtable, y le de al botón eliminar, no se elimine (ya que tiene foreing key y no quiero borrado en cascada), sino que se oculte en la base de datos y cuando cargue esa tabla en el jtable, ese registro no salga porque se ha ocultado.
Agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Cómo se haría directamente en la base de datos? Ni idea. Lo que yo implementé es un campo Estatus en cada tabla, que tiene dos valores: A (activo) B (borrado). Cuando algún usuario "borra" un registro, este campo lo cambio a B. Toda consulta que hago a la base de datos tiene `where Estatus='A'`. Desconozco si habrá una forma más elegante...

Comment: Muchas gracias pues haré eso

Answer (score -1):

No se si eso es posible,pero lo que yo haría es un trigger (disparador) en mysql que cuando un registro sea eliminado de una tabla, este se guarde automáticamente en otra tabla

Comment: ¿Me podrías decir como hacerlo por favor?